# Create Firefox addon to fix broken webpage on the fly

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon

At my job they use a "central login" facility on internal webpages.  Whenever an internal webpage requires authentication, it forwards you to the central login, and after logging in, it sends you back to the page you were trying to view.

The very first line in the HTML for this central login page starts with this:

```
<!-- Encoding=ISO-8859-1;
```

But it **never** ends the comment, which means that all the HTML code in the whole document is actually commented out.  This works fine in IE6 (which is the company standard - eek!), and it used to work in Firefox, but when I upgraded to Firefox 4, this no longer works (as it shouldn't - it is following standards).

I have saved the source and changed the first line to:

```
<!-- Encoding=ISO-8859-1; -->
```

And then the page will display, but since it is loaded from `file:///`, I can't submit my credentials to the main server...

I hate using IE6, but for all internal pages I am stuck with it because Firefox renders an empty page every time I get sent to the central login.

Is it possible to create a Firefox addon (or even a Greasemonkey script) to modify the HTML as it is coming into the browser before it gets rendered?  I see tons of examples of modifying HTML once it is already loaded, but can't find anything to manipulate *while* loading it.

I guess I'm open to other solutions besides an addon, but that was the only thing I could think of.  Also, we are not allowed to use Chrome or Safari, so that is out.  And no, I cannot talk to the person in charge of the central login page and get them to change it.  Proxying would probably be very difficult too because of the nature of the page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What a holy mess :) I love it, +1

Comment: +1 out of sympathy. What a mess.

Comment: @Henry and @delnan - I appreciate the sympathy.  It's hilarious because tickets for this have been opened by the other black sheep (Firefox users) and the standard response is "Use the standard browser" (IE6).  Actually, that's not so hilarious now that I think about it...

Comment: There is a special place in hell for those who forcibly mandate the use of IE6 ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Well, I'm sure the people who mandate IE6 do so because all of the stuff they coded won't work in any other browser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a local Apache with mod_proxy and mod_subsitute could be used for this? Derived from an example from [berkek.com](http://www.bergek.com/2008/10/10/proxy-a-web-site-and-change-the-content-on-the-fly/):

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerAdmin postmaster@yourcorp.com
  ServerName www.yourcompany.com
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
  </Proxy>
  ProxyRequests on
  ProxyPass / http://www.yourcompany.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://www.yourcompany.com/
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
  Substitute "s|<!-- Encoding=ISO-8859-1;|<!-- Encoding=ISO-8859-1; -->|n"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I didn't know about ProxyPassReverse, so maybe that would work.  To my comment to the previous answer - won't proxying slow all my browsing down, just to fix 1 login page?  (Granted, my browsing is a horrible experience currently since I'm in IE6)

Comment: You can of course configure your browser to only use the proxy on the sites you need this fix. See e.g. [proxy pac file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)

Comment: The pac file works well.  However, I cannot get the substitution to work.  I installed XAMPP and added a virtual host with the substitute lines.  It serves the page but won't substitute.  I even did a substitute of `s|a|BLAH|ni` but it still wouldn't work.  Found lots of docs, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method I found:

The [Fiddler Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com).  It is basically doing what @Tatu Lahtela [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967714/create-firefox-addon-to-fix-broken-webpage-on-the-fly/5969563#5969563) and what @alex [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967714/create-firefox-addon-to-fix-broken-webpage-on-the-fly/5969475#5969475), only without apache.

Here are the steps I took:

1. [Download](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp) and install Fiddler
2. Run Fiddler, which listens on port 8888 (by default)
3. In the Fiddler options (HTTPS tab), check the "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" box
4. In Fiddler, click the Rules Menu, then Customize Rules.
5. In my text editor, I found the `OnBeforeResponse` function, and added this code:

   ```
   if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "html")){
     // Remove any compression or chunking    
     oSession.utilDecodeResponse();

     var oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);

     var oRegEx = /<!-- Encoding=ISO-8859-1; /gi;
     oBody = oBody.replace(oRegEx, "<!-- Encoding=ISO-8859-1;  -->");

     oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody);
   }
   ```
6. In Fiddler, under Tools->Options->Connections tab, click "Copy browser Proxy Configuration URL" (This is the proxy PAC file that @Tatu Lahtela mentioned).
7. In Firefox, Tools->Options->Advanced Tab->Network Tab->Settings, check "Automatic Proxy Configuration URL and paste in the URL from step #6.
8. Surf the web!

I modified the PAC file to limit the sites that went to Fiddler like @Tatu Lahtela suggested.

This works for me, with minimal setup.  A Firefox addon would be better for me since I wouldn't have to use an external program, but building one to do this seems pretty difficult.

Thanks to everyone who helped!  I will mark @Tatu Lahtela 's answer as the accepted answer since that is how I was able to find what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

What are your reasons for not using a proxy?

Apache's httpd + mod_proxy + mod_ext_filter should solve your problems easily; you use mod_ext_filter to plug in a program which will fix the page (small shell script should do).

Comment: hmm - I don't really want all of my browsing to be through a proxy -  just for one page (the login page).  Won't mod_ext_filter slow all of my browsing down?  (not too familiar with it)

Comment: mod_proxy w/ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse is not the common proxy. You access http://newapacheserver/path and it sends the request to http://borkedappserver/path, you don't have to configure a proxy in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a Firefox addon, but it's a fair amount of work. http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/ shows you what to do, except instead of just taking the incoming data, storing it in an array, and sending it back to `originalListener`, you need to send the modified data (in your case, the data with the `-->` added) to the `originalListener`.